# Assistance needed with publishing a front-end html website with Github pages

Tags: html, github, github-pages, github-actions

So, uh, I'm really new to Github and would like to publish my Custom Seller Website (4 pages with interconnectivity, and an img folder with the pictures I use) via Github Pages. I have all 4 pages and the img folder in my repository, I deleted the description.md file (cause that was showing in the published page url) but it still shows the description when I go to the domain (username.github.io/...).. Any help is welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to host your website

1. First create a new repository in github
2. Then push your code after your relevant commit to the github using `git push -u origin master`
3. Then go to settings in the repository
4. Go to the github pages section
5. Choose master from the dropdown under the source and click save
6. After refreshing the page you will see your website url under the github pages section

Comment: How do I push the code as you say? Do I need a workflow too? I want the Home page to be displayed by default

Comment: You can refer to this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-push-an-existing-project-to-github

Comment: ok thanks, I'll take a look at it and get back to you if I have any further questions :D

Comment: So, I followed the steps but i get a fatal error on the last step (Could not read from remote repository).

Comment: *UPDATE* : All good, managed to create key and do the upload, thanks a lot!